# Bash command to check available drive space (was "to check value of a decimal number")

Tags: bash

I have this code, which checks that the remaining disk space on a specific drive and then runs a set of commands.

```
if [ "$(echo "$(df -h | awk '$1 == "drive_name" {print $4}' | sed 's/[T]//') >= 0.2" | bc)" -eq 1 ]; then 
    <run_these_commands>; 
else 
    <run_other_commands>; 
fi
```

It works, but the `[]` `test` is a mess. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do it all in awk.

Comment: @rici, I've gotten this far `df -h | awk '$1 == "gpfs0" {sub(/T/, "", $4); print $4}'`. How do I check equality in `awk`? I tried `df -h | awk '$1 == "gpfs0" {sub(/T/, "", $4)} > 4.1'` based on https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/56223-awk-greater-than.html but got a syntax error near the `>`.

Comment: `exit $4 > 0.2;` would cause awk to exit with status 0 (success) if $4 is less than or equal to 0.2, and status 1 (failure) if $4 is greater than 0.2. You can test the status return directly with the shell `if` statement: `if cmd; then ... ; else ...; fi` does the `then` block if `cmd` succeeds and otherwise the `else` block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it all with proper `df` arguments:

```sh
declare -- drive='/'
declare -i minsize=$((2*10**11)) # 200 GB
if (($(df -B1 --output=avail "$drive" | tail -1)>=minsize))
then
   printf 'There is more than 200 GB left on %s\n' "$drive"
else
   printf 'There is less than 200 GB left on %s\n' "$drive"
fi
```

`df`:

- `-B1`: Sets display block size to 1 byte, so it is always an integer.
- `--output=avail`: Displays only available space field.
- `"$drive"`: Show only for device or mountpoint

`| tail`:

- `-1`: Show only last line (skip header lines, so it returns only the integer byte amount of free space).

`((…))`: Bash allows stand-alone arithmetic, so use it in the `if` condition. Since only integer values are dealt with, it can be handled natively by the shell without need for `bc`.

Answer (score 1):

As a list of iterative improvements, I'd suggest the following:

- Instead of comparing the output of `bc` to `1`, use the `((...))` conditional construct, which returns a successful exit status for `1`, i.e., translates the output of `bc` directly. This allows us to drop the outermost command substitution and `-eq 1`:

  ```
  if (($(echo "$(df -h | awk '$1 == "drive_name" {print $4}' | sed 's/[T]//') >= 0.2" | bc))); then
  ```
- Instead of `echo "$(cmd) >= 0.2 | bc`, we can use `bc <<< "$cmd >= 0.2"`, which saves us a subshell and is a little shorter:

  ```
  if (($(bc <<< "$(df -h | awk '$1 == "drive_name" {print $4}' | sed 's/[T]//') >= 0.2"))); then
  ```
- The `T` in the sed command doesn't need to go into square brackets, it's not special:

  ```
  if (($(bc <<< "$(df -h | awk '$1 == "drive_name" {print $4}' | sed 's/T//') >= 0.2"))); then
  ```
- In fact, we don't need sed at all to remove the `T`:

  ```
  if (($(bc <<< "$(df -h | awk '$1 == "drive_name" {sub(/T/, "", $4); print $4}') >= 0.2"))); then
  ```
- We also don't need `bc`, because awk can compare to 0.2 itself:

  ```
  if (($(df -h | awk '$1 == "drive_name" {sub(/T/, "", $4); print $4 >= 0.2}'))); then
  ```
- We can get rid of the whole `T` business by not using the `-h` flag and comparing to kilobytes instead of terabytes:

  ```
  if (($(df | awk '$1 == "drive_name" {print $4 >= 0.2*1e9}'))); then
  ```

  (This is actually not exactly the same, as `df -h` uses multiples of 1024, but probably good enough.)
- We can tell `df` to just tell us about the filesystem we're interested in, then we know for sure the information we want is on the second line of output:

  ```
  if (($(df drive_name | awk 'NR == 2 {print $4 >= 0.2*1e9}'))); then
  ```
- We can have `df` give us just the available space:

  ```
  if (($(df --output=avail drive_name | awk 'NR == 2 {print $1 >= 0.2*1e9}'))); then
  ```
- And finally, we can make the comparison in Bash directly, we just need something to delete the first line of `df` output:

  ```
  if (($(df --output=avail drive_name | sed '1d') >= 2*10**8)); then
  ```

  Notice that we've switched from `0.2e9` to `2 * 10**8` to get around using floating point.

Comment: Leaving this up as a longwinded way to arrive at the same result as in Lea's answer; contains a few generally valid pointers along the way.

Answer (score 0):

For simple command you can use:

```
[ $(df -m --output=avail /|tail -n1) -lt 200 ] && echo issue || echo not issue
```

or with **if** to make it more readable:

```
if [ $(df -m --output=avail /|tail -n1) -lt 200 ]; then
 commands
else
  commands
fi
```

-m means megabytes. You can use test command to compare (-lt means less then)