# df -h if freespace equals then | bash

Tags: bash, terminal

The error that I am getting is with the df command on mac, I would like to specify a value in gigabytes and perhaps allow the user to choose a different drive if / is full.

```
destination="$HOME/Desktop/sandbox"

if [ $(df -h --output=avail /|tail -n1) -lt 300000 ]; then

    echo "There is less than 300GB available..." ;
    exit

else

    for files in *.tar ; do echo copying "$files" ; cp "$files" "$destination" ; read -n 1 -p "Press any key..." ; done
fi
```

**Not sure if** df -h / | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'  | sed 's/..$//' is a good option

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: `-h` means "human readable". That's probably not a switch you want to use when you want a script to parse the value.

Comment: maybe df -h / | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'  | sed 's/..$//'

Comment: This question is extremely similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61035374/3266847), yet the self answer is a regression back to an approach that is much worse. Additionally, it should contain information about the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
destination="$HOME/Desktop/sandbox"

freespace="$(df -h / | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/..$//')"

if  [ "$freespace" -lt 300 ]; then

    echo "There is less than 300GB available..." ;
    exit

else

    for files in *.sh ; do echo copying "$files" ; cp "$files" "$destination" ; read -n 1 -p "Press any key..." ; done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `dh -h` what means "human readable" and always append unit after the number (M, G, k...). There is a lot of options how to cut it out by `grep`, `awk`, `cut` or `sed`. But perhaps the best way is to use different option e.g. `df -m` to have an output in megabytes and multiply the required space.

Also I would propose to add a `grep $destination` (mountpoint visible in df output) to filter the required FS and to not rely that it's always last line in the output.

Try something like this:

```
destination="$HOME/Desktop/sandbox"

free_space=$(df -h | grep $destination | awk '{print $4}')

if [ $free_space -lt $((300 * 1024)) ]; then

    echo "There is less than 300GB available..." ;
    exit

else

    for files in *.tar; do
        echo copying "$files"
        cp "$files" "$destination"
        read -n 1 -p "Press any key..."
    done
fi
```